# Extend attributes for the InspectorControls in Gutenberg block javascript files via php

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I have a registered custom block file that has several attributes like this:

```
// block.js
registerBlockType( 'my-blocks/block-name', {
    title: 'My precious',
    icon: blockIcon,
    category: 'media',
    attributes: {
        autoplayTime: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 0
        },
        defaultType: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'foo' // <- I want this to be changed dynamically
        },
    },

    edit: ( props ) => {
        const {
            attributes: {
                autoplayTime,
                defaultType,
            },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        return (
            <div className="block">
                <InspectorControls>
                 // ...
```

Now I want to have the default value for the "defaultType" attribute changed dynamically based on certain backend options.

**Solution 1:**
use wp_localize_script() like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995462/
Works perfectly.

**Solution 2:**
remove the attributes object completely from the registerBlockType() in JS and pass them all by PHP while registering the block with

```
//in php
register_block_type(
 'my-blocks/block-name', 
     ['attributes' => 
         ['autoplayTime' => ['type' =>  'number' , 'default' => 0 // ...and so on ]
     ])
```

Works too, but is a little inelegant in my opinion, especially if I'd had to pass a lot of attributes, even if only one of them had to be dynamic.
Just passing one attribute to the JS while any other attributes are already defined there won't work, because any passed attribute would be ignored.

So is there be a clean and simple way to override/extend these attributes for the JS?

Thanks in advance.